# Congratulations to James(100)K

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, users

Congratulations to JamesK on his 100k-hood on Astronomy SE.

1452 answers (and 5 questions). It's a lot! Also - 2.2m "reached", which is an importantly large number.

Comment: @JamesK Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations JamesK and thank you for so many clear and labor-intensive answers and for welcoming new users and helping them improve their questions. https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/important_person.html and https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/leader

Comment: Wow! Congratulations @JamesK I began adding my own stats and found I have reached 40,470 people across the sites I use most often. That's not even close to him!